# Shaded Pole motor - change RPM by relative change to windings

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I've got a small shaded pole motor (C-type) that I'm cannibalizing for use in a project,  but the current RPM is too high.  I don't want to spend the effort to build a micro-controller to run it.

Is there a way to easily change the RPM by making a relative change to the wound coil?  For instance,  it's currently running at 2750 RPM,  it's 80W, 220V and there are 1500 windings on the coil.  Without going into serious design formulas and discussions,  are there 'rules of thumb' that I can use to change the RPM?  For instance, to half the RPM, half the number of windings, double the wire gauge, or something similar.  I'm not aiming at a specific target (RPM wise) I just want it slower - somewhere between one third,  and a half of the current RPM.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could not easily change the speed of a shaded pole motor, but my wife has a small fan she keeps by her side of the bed that has a slide switch to select "low" and high." The bearing in the back of the motor is getting fussy, so It's time for a new motor. I happened to find an unused one in my junk box (it probably was for a bathroom ceiling vent) so I planning on swapping out the motor and reconnect the "High-Low" switch. I suspect there is some sort of L-C network involved but will share the details after I get to swapping it out. Thinking back, I guess I w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shaded pole motor is a type of induction motor, just using some neat magnetic tricks to generate a second phase. It runs at slightly below synchronous speed, the slip depends on the torque.

For a simple 2 pole motor, you'd expect it to run at perhaps 90% of 3000 rpm (50 Hz countries), or 3600 rpm (60 Hz). This is what you are seeing.

If you reduce the voltage, with a series inductor or resistor, the motor will produce less power and depending on the load, the speed will drop and the slip increase. However the torque drops very quickly at reduced speeds, so it's unlikely you will get anywhere near as low as 50% of synchronous speed.

I think that removing turns, keeping the voltage constant, will increase the current and make it run slightly faster against the same load.

[This site](http://www.johnsonelectric.com/en/resources-for-engineers/motors/motor-design-considerations/shaded-pole-motors.html) has some diagrams and specifications. The speed when running below rated speed will be very dependent on the torque curve of the load.

So unfortunately you can only reliably reduce the speed of the motor by reducing the AC supply frequency (and voltage) with a variable speed drive.

Comment: OK - thanks for the input!  How does a shaded pole fan motor achieve its different speeds then?  Is this done with supply frequency as you explained? I assumed this was with different windings being selected by the push buttons.

Comment: That's a good question, I don't really know. I'd speculate that they energise only one winding, then both in series, then both in parallel. The torque of a fan is proportional to the square of speed, and hence power to speed cubed, so the speed variation might be 70%,88%,100% for a fair range of "speeds". If the fan example is slow enough for you, then try dropping the voltage and seeing how it goes.

Comment: if the load is a soft load like a fan, speed control operates by reducing current through the windings and thus increasing the slip. for a fan it's often a series capacitor that's used for speed control.

Comment: Thank you all for the information - I've got a fair idea of what I need to do - much appreciated.

Comment: @jasen I've just tried adding a capacitor in series with my shaded pole fan, hoping to make it go slower... It went faster! The C resonated with the L in the motor, and it saw a higher voltage. I can also confirm that the winding has several taps.

Comment: Resonating the leakage inductance of the motor is a neat trick, but a smaller capacit.or (eg half what you used)  should work to reduce the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Those answers are just mumbo-jumbo-babble. Just use a rheostat at 1000 ohms and plenty of amps ratings. Ohmite makes the best. A rheostat varies the current going through the motor. Research it and you'll see that I'm right. Not many people knows that. Laboratory stir plate are made with a shaded pole motor, a switch and a rheostat. That's all. And their speed is variable from 5% to 100%. Be careful, the rheostat gets hot. It's supposed to do that. That's why the windings are made of nichrome wire wrapped around a ceramic core. Good luck.